# Counting up scores from a text file - Java

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, count

I'm trying to count up scores that are in a text file. In this text file some of the scores are replaced with x's and these are anomalies. I've tried different things to try and get this right but the score total is always 0! If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great! Thanks :)

```
while (txtFileScan.hasNext()) {
    //Splits the array into lines and splits it, it then adds up what's in arrayStore[2] and [3].
    String ln = txtFileScan.nextLine();
    String[] arrayStore = ln.split(":");
    if (arrayStore.length == 4) {
        System.out.printf(arrayStore[0], arrayStore[2], arrayStore[1], arrayStore[3]);
        //If statements: if arrays are null, nested if to check if there are any x's.
        if (arrayStore[2] != null && arrayStore[3] != null) {
            if (arrayStore[2].trim().indexOf("x") >= 0 && arrayStore[3].trim().indexOf("x") >= 0) {
                total = Integer.parseInt(arrayStore[2] + arrayStore[3]);
            }
        }
    }
}

Leeds United : Liverpool : 1 : 2
Chelsea :  Manchester City : 1 : 1
Aston Villa : Middlesbrough : 3 : 1
Tottenham Hotspur : Stoke City : 0 : 0
West Ham United : Wigan Athletic :2 : 1
Fulham : Liverpool : 1 : 2
Wigan Athletic : Leeds United : 2 : 2
Arsenal Liverpool :2:2
Hull City: Tottenham Hotspur : 3 : 5
Everton : Portsmouth:4 : 2
Stoke City : West Bromwich Albion : 5 : 4
Leeds United : Liverpool : 1: 10
Blackburn Rovers : Fulham : 1 : 1
West Ham United : Newcastle United : 0 : 0
Manchester United : Wigan Athletic : 1 : 2
Hull City : Sunderland : 2 : 3
Chelsea : Manchester City :1
Fulham : Leeds United : 1 : 2
Wigan Athletic : Tottenham Hotspur : 2 : 2
Hull City : Everton : 3 : 5
: :2:0
Sunderland : Blackburn Rovers : 4 : 2
Stoke City : West Bromwich Albion : 5 : 4
Hull : Liverpool : 5: x
Blackburn Rovers : Fulham : 1 : 1
Chelsea  : Everton : a : 1
Sunderland : Newcastle United : 0 : 0
Hull : :2:3
Sunderland : Blackburn Rovers : 1 : 2
Hull City : Everton : 2 : 3
Leeds United : Chelsea : 1 : 2
Chelsea : Manchester City : 1 : 1
Aston Villa:Fulham:3:1
Manchester City : Stoke City : 0 : 0
West Ham United : Middlesbrough : 2 : 1
```

Comment: How are the scores laid out in the file?

Comment: Could you provide the input file?

Comment: I'll get a screenshot. 1 second

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/a1uq0qlen/

Comment: @Uyyyfgfar Don't give us a screenshot. Copy and paste that into the body of your question.

Comment: Sorry @newbiedoodle there we go

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: @Uyyyfgfar It looks like you have some malformed data, actually. Things like `Chelsea : Manchester City :1` and `: :2:0` are probably not supposed to be formatted like that.

Comment: @Uyyyfgfar In addition, you'll want to check out your printf statement -- The syntax should be more like `System.out.printf("%s: %s; %s: %s", arrayStore[0], arrayStore[2], arrayStore[1], arrayStore[3])` with a pattern up front.

Answer (score 0):

In your if condition, you are only totalling lines which have "x" at position 2 and position 3.
This never happens in your sample input

I think what you want is to skip scores where one or the other score is x.  Therefore

if (arrayStore[2].trim().indexOf("x") == -1 && arrayStore[3].trim().indexOf("x") == -1)

{

total = Integer.parseInt(arrayStore[2] + arrayStore[3]);

}

You may also have further work for total.

Comment: Surely should be || rather than &&

Comment: The parseInt statement is called on a concatenation of the two fields. That won't work.

Comment: sprinter was correct that my if condition was incorrect. I have edited the answer and tested it locally. The matter of how "total" is calculated is ambiguous to me. It seems the most likely solution is total = Integer.parseInt(arrayStore[2]) + Integer.parseInt(arrayStore[3])

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions for you:

1. the `printf` statement looks like it's intended to be for tracing? Check out the `Logger` class - you'll find that to be much more useful in the long term. In this case you likely mean `println` rather than  `printf`.
2. The `String` class has a `contains` method - that's a more intuitive use than `indexOf`.
3. You might want to look at regexp or scanners rather than split. Regexp will automatically filter out your 'x' anomolies by looking at lines that have numbers in the relevant place and can ignore spaces in badly formatted lines.
4. Finally, you might want to look at using Perl rather than Java for this if it's all file based. This is a totally trivial piece of code in Perl.